# What are the steps to follow to do static testing of an iOS device??

Tags: ios, testing, static

I am now assigned to start the static testing of an Ios device. 
As we do the the static testing of any android device by extracting the apk file, then reading the permissions on the manifest file and so on. I have not really tried to do the same as I am not getting the proper approach. 
If there are any references or links that I can follow..

What approach to follow for ios device. Kindly help..!!!

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. iNalyzer
2. IPad File Explorer
3. HP Enterprise Software, etc are good tools for static analysis of iOS application

Here are some reference links, that will help you to get a good start,

http://blog.dornea.nu/2014/10/29/howto-ios-apps-static-analysis/
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/part-15-static-analysis-of-ios-apps-using-inalyzer/#gref